# Realm doesn't work with SLF4J?

Tags: realm

We wanted to integrate Realm in our app, and we encountered following problem:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: XService
    Process: xx.xxx.xxxx, PID: 16462
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/gradle/logging/internal/slf4j/OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext;
       at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:30)
       at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:27)
       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:279)
       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252)
       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:265)
       at xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.impl.core.StateMachine.<init>(StateMachine.java:52)
       at xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.android.XService$ServiceHandler.startController(XService.java:670)
       at xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.android.XService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(XService.java:536)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/xx.xxx.xxxx-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/xx.xxx.xxxx-2/lib/arm, /data/app/xx.xxx.xxxx-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
       at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:30) 
       at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:27) 
       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128) 
       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108) 
       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:279) 
       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252) 
       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:265) 
       at xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.impl.core.StateMachine.<init>(StateMachine.java:52) 
       at xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.android.XService$ServiceHandler.startController(XService.java:670) 
       at xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.android.XService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(XService.java:536) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext
       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Where StaticLoggerBinder looks like:

```
public class StaticLoggerBinder implements LoggerFactoryBinder {

    private static final StaticLoggerBinder SINGLETON = new StaticLoggerBinder();

    private static final String loggerFactoryClassStr = AndroidCustomLoggerFactory.class.getName();

    private final ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new AndroidCustomLoggerFactory();

    private StaticLoggerBinder() {
    }

    public static final StaticLoggerBinder getSingleton() {
       return SINGLETON;   // line 27
    }

    public ILoggerFactory getLoggerFactory() { //line 30
       return this.loggerFactory;
    }

    public String getLoggerFactoryClassStr() {
       return loggerFactoryClassStr;
    }
}
```

From my understanding, problem is probably with Realm's transformer. It wants to include some unknown logger to our code. Main problem with our app is, that we have some 3rd party library, that uses also SLF4J, and we can't modify it. I tried with 0.90.1 version, while SLF4J used by 3rd party library is in 1.6.4 version. Dexguard is 7.1.26.

Also, note that, Realm works with my environment and another project with same dependencies except this 3rd party library and SLF4J.

List of dependencies:

```
plugins:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'dexguard'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

dependencies:
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
compile([
        'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2',
        'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18',
        'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1',
        'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.11',
        'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0',
        'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0',
        'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0',
        'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0',
        'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
])
compile files('libs/libconceal.jar')
compile files('libs/conceal_android.jar')
compile files('../dexguard/dexguard-runtime.jar')

compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar')
compile files('libs/lib3rdparty.jar')

retrolambdaConfig 'net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda:2.3.0'
```

Is this possible, that Realm mess up here with that implementation? Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: What make you think the exception is related to Realm?

Comment: Everything was working till now, Realm is only difference between working and not working state.

Comment: Have you tried disabling DexGuard? Realm support should have been fixed in 7.1.26, but just to verify?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I tried with disabled DexGuard, with and without Proguard, but I'm still getting same error. Also edited stacktrace with more info.

Comment: Realm does not manipulate any classes that doesn't touch any Realm classes, and I don't see any of the code you posted doing that. Maybe it is related to Multidex?

Comment: Hm, not really. We have about ~45k methods with shrinked build. We don't have Multidex yet. Is realm that big, to pass 64k?

Comment: No, it adds about 2500 methods.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm running into the same problem. Before adding Realm to the project the logger was fine, but now I get a "Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory" error. It's not a MultiDex problem either.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no...

Comment: did you find any solution by now?